# How i can test, use XCTest with a REPL swift

Tags: ios, swift, testing, read-eval-print-loop

Is there any way i can use XCTest to test my REPL proj in Swift?

I created a new target, OSX Unit Testing Bundle, configured the target dependencie to my project, and try to use

```
@testable import test
```

declaring the class like this :

```
func testPath() {
    let archiever = Archieves()

}
```

I can declare, but when build and test, but i get the following error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test.Archieves.__allocating_init (test.Archieves.Type)() -> test.Archieves", referenced from:
      testTests.testTests.testPath (testTests.testTests)() -> () in testTests.o
  "type metadata accessor for test.Archieves", referenced from:
      testTests.testTests.testPath (testTests.testTests)() -> () in testTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```